# Comparisons with Pandas DataFrame columns of lists

Tags: python, list, pandas

I have a dataframe df like this:

```
col1 | col2
 a   | [1,2]
 b   | [3,4]
 c   | [3,9]
```

I want to get the row based on a matching input array, so if I have the array [1,2], I can get:

```
col1 | col2
 a   | [1,2]
```

When I try to do this using this formula, it doesn't work:

```
df.loc[df['Col2'] == [1,2]]
Error: Lengths must match to compare
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The real cause of your error was that not all lists are of the same size, this causes issues with `DataFrame.eq`.

The best approach to tackling this is to build a boolean mask using a list comprehension and then use it to index into `df`:

```
df[[v == [1, 2] for v in df['col2'].tolist()]]
```

Another alternative is `df.apply`, but that isn't nearly as fast as this.

Comment: @NBC Not sure what you're doing, but you're likely doing it wrong (it works for this example quite well)

Comment: @jezrael the answer there did not apply to this because it did not explain the error OP was getting. But this answer is applicable for that question hence I reversed it. Hope it's clear now.